# How to access the fixture from conftest file before setup_class method or in setup_class?

Tags: python, class, pytest, fixtures

I have a fixture in confest file while I will not be able to move into my module.
I have created a Testclass with setup_class and teardown_class.
In setup class I have called 2 setup functions which in turns prepare my setup.
But I need the fixture object from conftest file in those two setup functions. Is there any way to access it?

```
Eg:

> class TestClass():
>     @classmethod
>     def setup_class(cls):
>         cls.setup_apps()
>         cls.stub_apps()
> 
>     @classmethod
>     def teardown_class(cls):
>         cls.unstub_apps()
```

I need to access the whatever the fixture returns in setup_apps,stub_apps and unstub_apps method. It is not possible for me to move the fixture into my module.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what is the need for this to be a fixture?

Comment: It is already a fixture which is used by other multiple test files